# Convert data to array of unique values

Tags: php, arrays

I am iterating over JSON data from an API like so:

```
$data = file_get_contents(endpoint); // this is a WordPress func
$parsed_json = json_decode($data, true);

foreach($parsed_json as $unit_floor_data) {
    $unit_floor_data["Beds"] ...
}
```

This is where I get stuck. `$unit_floor_data` var_dump `string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "2" string(1) "2" string(1) "3" string(1) "4"`. The goal is to have an array such as [1, 2, 3, 4] that I can iterate over and use in outputted HTML like so:

```
$output = '<div id="property_floorplan" class="checkbox-container">';
        $output .= '<label>Refine:</label>';

        $output .= '<div class="checkbox-inline"><label class="bedrooms"><input type="checkbox" data-bedrooms="1">'.$bed_number.' Bed</label></div>' ;
        ..and so on...
```

Here's a snippet of the var_dump of $parsed_json

```
array(6) { [0]=> array(18) { ["PropertyId"]=> string(6) "167675" ["FloorplanId"]=> string(6) "972907" ["FloorplanName"]=> string(11) "Blue Bonnet" ["Beds"]=> string(1) "1" ["Baths"]=> string(4) "1.00" ["MinimumSQFT"]=> string(3) "701" ["MaximumSQFT"]=> string(3) "701" ["MinimumRent"]=> string(2) "-1" ["MaximumRent"]=> string(2) "-1" ["MinimumDeposit"]=> string(1) "0"
```

Obviously, PHP is not my strong point and I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you give an example of $parsed_json, or just the output from performing a var_dump($parsed_json); And can you elaborate on your foreach loop...

Comment: "_I'm not sure if it's an array, but they are strings._"...? Please rephrase.

Comment: What is that "1" in `data-bedrooms="1"`? Does it relates with the corresponding `$bed_number` value, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<?php

$data = '{
            "0" : {"Beds" : 1},
            "1" : {"Beds" : 1},
            "2" : {"Beds" : 1},
            "3" : {"Beds" : 2},
            "4" : {"Beds" : 3},
            "5" : {"Beds" : 4},
            "13" : {"Beds" : 13}
        }';

$parsed_json = json_decode($data, true);

// List of unique "beds" values. Indexed array.
$bedsList = [];

foreach ($parsed_json as $unit_floor_data) {
    $beds = $unit_floor_data['Beds'];

    // Append the "beds" value to the $bedsList, if not already. 
    if (!in_array($beds, $bedsList)) {
        $bedsList[] = $beds;
    }
}

$output = '<div id="property_floorplan" class="checkbox-container">';
$output .= '<label>Refine:</label>';

// Create a div with checkbox for each item in $bedsList.
foreach ($bedsList as $key => $beds) {
    $output .= '<div class="checkbox-inline">';
    $output .= '<label class="bedrooms">';
    $output .= '<input type="checkbox" data-bedrooms="' . $beds . '">' . $beds . ' Beds';
    $output .= '</label>';
    $output .= '</div>';
}

$output .= '</div>'; /* End of "property_floorplan" div */

echo $output;
```

A suggestion: try to avoid printing html code from php. Use php snippets inside the html part, not the inverse.

Good luck.